# Android Studio displaying white boxes instead of file contents

Tags: android, encoding, android-studio

Recently my computer crashed when Android Studio was open.
When I opened it agan it showed me that my Android Studio Settings couldnt be loaded and it shows this on the manifes

```
Êþº¾   2 8    *
 + ,  -
  .
  / 
  /      0    1    2    3 4 NONE 
Lorg/gradle/api/PathValidation; EXISTS FILE   DIRECTORY 
$VALUES  [Lorg/gradle/api/PathValidation; values "() 
[Lorg/gradle/api/PathValidation; Code LineNumberTable valueOf 
3(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/gradle/api/PathValidation; 
LocalVariableTable name Ljava/lang/String; <init> 
(Ljava/lang/String;I)V this     Signature ()V <clinit> 
1Ljava/lang/Enum<Lorg/gradle/api/PathValidation;>; 
SourceFile PathValidation.java    5 6 
org/gradle/api/PathValidation  7 ! "         
java/lang/Enum clone ()Ljava/lang/Object; 
5(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum;@1     @    
@    @    @                   "      
² ¶ À °                    4     
*¸ À °                   
       ! "     1     *+· ±                    #    
$    %  & %     p      T» Y· ³     » Y
· ³ » Y· ³ 
» Y· ³ ½ Y²    SY² SY² 
SY² S³ ±       
     4   $    ' (    )
```

I first tought that my code was corrupted but when I open the "corrupted" files on any text editor they are fine.
I tried invalidating the caches, and deleting workspace.xml, but the problem persist.

Do you know what might be causing this and how can I correct it?

Comment: Reinstall AndroidStudio.

Comment: It didnt work. Reinstalled Android Studio, imported the project again and still showed the boxes. Ended up creating a new project and copying and pasting the files to the new project. But my android studio is still acting weird. Im deleting all the caches to see if it returns to normal.